# Prime Factorization of First 1000 Numbers in C++

Tags: c++, factorization

I need to write a program that could find the sums of the prime factors of the first 1000 numbers, check if the sums are prime, and print them if they are.

I have some pseudo-code I've written and I have a working program for generating prime numbers that I'm trying to expand off of.  I'm learning from the book "Jumping into C++," by the way (it's a Practice Problem in the book).

This is the pseudo-code:

```
// for every 1000 of the first bunch of numbers, check if the number is prime
// if (number isPrime())
// use expression <number_being_checked % number_being_compared_against == 0;>

// if (number_being_checked % number_being_compared_against == 0)
// for every number found from dividing the two numbers, check if number is prime
// add up prime numbers and check if the sums are prime

// else, return false in bool function isFactorPrime() (if I write such a function)
```

And this is the main() function right now:

```
int main ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {

        if (isFactorPrime(i))
        {
            cout << i 
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having right now is about what I should add to i (i + some_variable?) to get my sum that I can use in my check to see if it's a prime number.  Should I make an inner for-loop and then add loop-variable in that to i, with expression i + j?  Where I'd assign j the value of the number being checked (which is what I'm wondering how I could do.  It's not like I'm going to take the user's input, I'm just iterating over the first 1000 numbers and checking them).

There are also some other Practice Problems in the book I need to ask help with, but for now I'll go with just this one.

Comment: Can't you just add `i` to a sum, and check that?

Comment: Could you give me an example to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: The first paragraph says to "sum the prime factors" so you need to factor each number (1 to 1000)  and add up the factors.  You need to decide if 1 or N count as factors.  Since 8 = 2 * 2 * 2, sum of factors = 6, since 10 = 2 * 5, sum of factors = 7.  Ahah 7 is prime, so you print 10.

Comment: Would j = sqrt(double)i); j < i; j++; and then i + j work?

Comment: I tried doing that in main(), but now the program's output is just that the Operating System returned 0.  I want to send the code for it in a PM or email to someone who has a good enough understanding of C++ who could help me with this.  Who should I message?